# jquery submit one form when page has more than one form

Tags: jquery

I have a page with two forms. ID="form2" and ID="form3".

Form3 is within Form2. 
Inside Form3, there is a button with a jquery action to submit form3 but when I click on it, nothing happens.

This is written in Classic ASP and JQuery.

This is form2

```
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="process/processeditjob.asp">
```

and within this, there is the following form:

```
<form id="form3" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadscript1.asp">
<INPUT TYPE="FILE" SIZE="40" NAME="FILE1"><br />
<INPUT ID="goupload" TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="Upload!">
</form>
```

The Jquery linked to the button is as follows:

```
    $('#goupload').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("entered");
    $('#form3').attr('action', "uploadscript1.asp").submit();
    });
```

When I click on the button, I can see the alert message saying entered.

If I move form3 to a new page, it works perfectly.

I am not sure as to why it is not submitting within the first form.

Thanks
Saj

Comment: you can't have a form within another one - html form can have block and script elements a children not other forms

Comment: chrome removes the outer form - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FvEcU/1/

Comment: Is there a particular reason for form2 to share the same elements as form3? Maybe what you want are two different buttons in the same form submitting to different pages?